# Convert color code to float array in android

Tags: android, android-layout, colormatrixfilter

colors resource file:

```
<color name="red">#ffff5454</color>
```

code:

```
int color = Resources.getColor(getResources().Color.red);

// how to get paramArrayOfFloat from color?

ColorMatrix localColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
localColorMatrix.setSaturation(0.0F);
localColorMatrix.set(paramArrayOfFloat);
```

how can I get `paramArrayOfFloat` from my color number? I want to convert my number to float array. Is this possible in android?

Comment: Above both method start small "s" instead of caps "S".

Comment: sorry mistake from typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ColorMatrix:

> 4x5 matrix for transforming the color+alpha components of a Bitmap.
>   The matrix is stored in a single array, and its treated as follows: [
>   a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t ] When
>   applied to a color [r, g, b, a], the resulting color is computed as
>   (after clamping) R' = a*R + b*G + c*B + d*A + e; G' = f*R + g*G + h*B
>   + i*A + j; B' = k*R + l*G + m*B + n*A + o; A' = p*R + q*G + r*B + s*A + t;

**For red color -**

```
 float[] colorTransform = {
        0, 1f, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0f, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0f, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 1f, 0};

ColorMatrix localColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
localColorMatrix.setSaturation(0.0F); //Remove Colour 
localColorMatrix.set(colorTransform); //Apply Red say
```

For more check: [ColorMatrixSample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/ColorMatrixSample.htm) and [ColorMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html).

**NOTE:**

You can check the link for [converting-a-web-color-to-an-rgb-float-array-for-after-effects](http://www.creative-workflow-hacks.com/2006/05/29/converting-a-web-color-to-an-rgb-float-array-for-after-effects/).

Comment: Thank you. So there is no generic solution to convert from Hec color number to array?